# Check if a key is a valid key for the current app id

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Is there a way or a function to check if a key is a valid key for the current app id?

e.g.

```
key = fetch_urlsafe_key_from_external_source()
key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key)
if not is_valid_key(key):
  return
# do something with the key
```

EDIT: For the moment I'm doing

```
def is_valid_key(key):
  try:
    key.get()
  except datastore_errors.BadRequestError:
    return False
  return True
```

But hopefully someone suggests something that doesn't requiring hitting the datastore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for correct application ID included in the key:

```
import os

def is_valid_key(key):
  """Valid key should include an ID and current application ID.
  """
  if key.app() == os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID') and key.id():
    return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def is_valid_key(key):
  try:
    key.id()
  except TypeError:
    return False
  return True
```

**EDIT**:

I know realize that OP wanted **application validation** not just key validation. The currently selected "correct" answer works in most cases but would still raise an exception if the key was incomplete/changed (i.e. missing some characters or having extra characters at the end of the string), the better way to validate would be:

```
def is_valid_key(key):
  try:
    key.id()
  except TypeError:
    return False
  return key.app() == os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID')
```